# I am trying to remove an item from my mongoDb object which is an object with an array of nested objects. But this code is not working

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I want to delete the object where the name is "Sleep".
The code I am using:

```
const listName = "Holiday;
  const item = new Item({
    name: "Sleep"
  });
  User.updateOne({username : req.user.username}, {$pull:{"lists.$[updateList].items" : item}}, {
    "arrayFilters": [
      {"updateList.name" : listName}
    ]
  }).exec().then(function(){
    console.log("Deleted successfully");
    res.redirect("/list-"+listName);
  })
```

The mongodb object:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("64797ebc9e84ed9d8be3ea54"),
  "username" : "aryan@gmail.com",
  "lists" : [
      {
          "name" : "Holiday",
          "items" : [
              {
                  "name" : "Welcome to your todo-list!",
                  "_id" : ObjectId("647988267f3ddfc2982f7d77")
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Click + to add another item.",
                  "_id" : ObjectId("647988267f3ddfc2982f7d78")
              },
              {
                  "name" : "<-- Click this to delete an item.",
                  "_id" : ObjectId("647988267f3ddfc2982f7d79")
              },
              {
                  "name" : "Sleep",
                  "_id" : ObjectId("64799279c3da415dc4ce7574")
              },
              {
                  "name" : "WakeUp",
                  "_id" : ObjectId("6479930e6d49e494aad1dffa")
              }
          ],
          "_id" : ObjectId("647988357f3ddfc2982f7d85")
      }
]
}
```

It seems there is some problem with the updateOne and $pull: attributes but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
const listName = 'Holiday';
User.updateOne(
  { username: req.user.username, 'lists.name': listName },
  { $pull: { 'lists.$[].items': { name: 'Sleep ' } } }
)
  .exec()
  .then(function () {
    console.log('Deleted successfully');
    res.redirect('/list-' + listName);
  });
```

Comment: The then function is successfully console logging and redirecting but the object is not updating. The item is still in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code, it's working fine.

Note: just write object id in findOne({_id}) function. No need to edit
it. Use this code inside asyn function

```
const user = await user.findOnde({_id:_id /*give object id here-- 
    commented*/});
 const user_lists= user.lists
 const deleted_item_name="Sleep"; // Change it, if you want to delete other then "Sleep" named items.
 let new_lists=[];
 let new_items=[];
     user_lists.forEach((obj,index)=>{
           
      new_items= obj.items.filter((inner_obj,i)=>{
           
        if(inner_obj.name!=deleted_item_name)
        {
          return inner_obj;
        }
      })
      new_lists.push({name:obj.name,items:new_items})

     })

     user.lists= new_lists;
     await user.save();
     res.status(200).json(new_lists);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).